# Dropdown not sticking when navigating back

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

Not sure what I am doing wrong but the info that I select does not stick anymore when I navigate to another page and then go back.

This is code that works. It's for a a regular attendee:

```
<div class="linegroup">
<label class="notrequired" id="dietaryNeed_g1">Meal Preferences</label>
<select name="dietaryNeedValue_g1" id="dietaryNeedValue_g1" class="lbl-col-right" onclick="mealPrefs();">
    <optgroup label="Please Select Your Meal Preferences">
        <%--<%=cache.getValueListHTML( "ALL_MEALCODE", addSelect, d)%>--%>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="DAIRY" <%if(formFields.getDisplayValue( "dietaryConsiderationsOther_g1").equalsIgnoreCase( "Dairy-Free")){ %>selected
                <%}%>>Dairy Free</option>
            <option value="FOODALLE" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "FOODALLE")%>>Food Allergy</option>
            <option value="KOSHER" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "KOSHER")%>>Kosher</option>
            <option value="HALAL" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "HALAL")%>>Halal</option>
            <option value="VEGAN" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "VEGAN")%>>Vegan</option>
            <option value="VEGTRIAN" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "VEGTRIAN")%>>Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="GLUTFREE" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "GLUTFREE")%>>Gluten-Free</option>
            <option value="OTHER" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g1", "OTHER")%>>Other</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This is the code for a guest. For some reason this drop down disappears whenever I go to the next page and then navigate back.

```
<div class="linegroup">
<label class="required" id="dietaryNeed_g<%=i%>">Meal Preferences</label>
<select name="dietaryNeedValue_g<%=i%>" id="dietaryNeedValue_g<%=i%>" data-parsley-trigger="focusout" class="firstselect lbl-col-right" onchange="mealPrefs();" novalidate>
    <optgroup label="Please Select Your Meal Preferences">
        <%--<%=cache.getValueListHTML( "ALL_MEALCODE", addSelect, d)%>--%>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="DAIRY" <%if(formFields.getDisplayValue( "dietaryConsiderationsOther_g"+ i).equalsIgnoreCase( "Dairy-Free")){ %>selected
                <%}%>>Dairy Free</option>
            <option value="FOODALLE" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "FOODALLE")%>>Food Allergy</option>
            <option value="KOSHER" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "KOSHER")%>>Kosher</option>
            <option value="HALAL" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "HALAL")%>>Halal</option>
            <option value="VEGAN" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "VEGAN")%>>Vegan</option>
            <option value="VEGTRIAN" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "VEGTRIAN")%>>Vegetarian</option>
            <option value="GLUTFREE" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "GLUTFREE")%>>Gluten-Free</option>
            <option value="OTHER" <%=formFields.getSelectValue( "dietaryNeedValue_g" + i, "OTHER")%>>Other</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Any ideas on how to make the Guest dropdown stick?

Comment: It looks like you are not accessing the "i" index correctly throughout the bottom.  Can you post a jsfiddle for your example?

Comment: does it lose selected value or just gets disappeared?